# Apache redirect one page to HTTP or HTTPS conditionally

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

The home page of our site doubles as both the login page and the main page where users can click links to content. I'm trying to make it so that when the home page is acting as the login page, it is using HTTPS and using HTTP on all other occasions. The home page acts as the login page when there is no user currently logged in (and I can check a cookie for this):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^((?!MY_LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME).)*$ # Cookie is not present
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%{SERVER_NAME} [R,L] # Redirect http://example.com to https://example.com
```

This brings an anonymous user to an SSL home page, as expected.

The problem is when the cookie does exist, how do make requests for the home page always redirect to the HTTP version and not the HTTPS version? (After a user logs in, they are taken back to the home page, but now it would show content).

I tried appending this to the end of the rules above:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*MY_LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME=([^;]+) # Cookie exists
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME} [R,L] # Redirect home page to HTTP only
```

This results in a redirect loop error, most likely because the regex matches the home page, redirects to http version, matches again, redirects to http version . . . infinitely.

Is there a way to make the home page redirect to HTTPS when the cookie is missing and to HTTP when it is present?

Comment: You realized that if you redirect logged user to the http version, someone can steal their cookies and usurp their identities ?

Comment: @Tom This was the decision of the higher ups, not mine. If it was up to me, I'd just use HTTPS throughout the site, but there's some issues with the ad people we work with that's preventing that.

Comment: I understand your position, and I hope you didn't store any important information.

Answer (score 0):

Can yo try these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !MY_LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%{SERVER_NAME} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} MY_LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME} [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. After trying this: The login page is HTTPS when it is reached by an anonymous user, but after they login they are taken back to the home page and it is still in HTTPS instead of HTTP. If I manually go to http://example.com while logged in, it will stay HTTP. Any suggestions for why it still goes to HTTPS after immediately after logging in?

Comment: Oops, I should have mentioned that my question was edited after I posted. I'm checking the same cookie in both cases, not two different cookies. But I still tried it and it gave me the same result as before.

Comment: There is no reason why updated rules should not work since both conditions are opposite. What's your Apache version? Do you have other rules as well?

Comment: There are no other rules in play, just the ones in your answer. Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

Comment: That means your `MY_LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME` cookie is not accessible from SSL site.

Comment: I dumped out the $_SERVER variable and I see the cookie name in the HTTP_COOKIE field. I was looking at the home page immediately after logging in (the page was HTTPS before I logged in and was still HTTPS after I had logged in). If I see it here does that necessarily mean that the SSL version of the page can access the cookie?

Comment: ok what happens when you comment out `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} MY_LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME [NC]` line in 2nd rule?

Comment: Same behavior. When I am not logged in, I can only access the HTTPS version of the page. After submitting the login form, I am taken to an HTTPS version of the home page, but I can still manually go to the HTTP version without being redirected back to HTTPS. So this means it can't access the cookie then?

Comment: No this means `%{HTTPS}` variable is not being set correctly by your Apache. Try my updated rule as last resort.